# TreeNode click event on ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4 (beta 3) and I have a TreePanel that is my kind of navigation menu.
It is something like this:

- Jobs

  - Add Job
  - List All Jobs
- ...

  - ...
  - ...

(this will be made on a permission system base, but that's another story)

On ExtJS 3, do something when i clicked "Add Job" was as simple as adding

```
...
leaf:true,
listeners:{
click:function(n){
       //my code...
   }
}
...
```

to the root children elements.

Now It's not that simple. The closer i got was with (on the treepanel)

```
listeners:{
    click : {
             element : 'el',
             fn : function(eve, elem, obj){
                   console.log(node);
                   console.log(elem);
                   console.log(obj);
                  }
    }
}
```

So, maybe i'm just a noob, maybe i have already a strong hatred for ExtJS, maybe is just a problem in this beta version, but...

How do I add a listener to the click event on the tree nodes? (the Select event won't do what i need)

Thank you guys.

EDIT: Currently testing with this, and it's not working.

```
 ... = Ext.create('Ext.tree.TreePanel', {
                        region      : 'west',
                        collapsible : false,
                        title       : 'ITMI',
                        width       : 220,
                        margins     : '5 5 5 5',
                        cmargins    : '5 5 5 5',
                        hideHeaders : true,
                        useArrows   : true,
                        rootVisible : false,
                        headers: [{
                                xtype    : 'treeheader',
                                text     : 'Nome',
                                flex     : 1,
                                dataIndex: 'nome'
                            }],
                        store: store,
                        listeners:{
                            itemclick: function(n){
                                console.info(n);
                            }
                        }
    ...
```

**EDIT 2:** The itemclick event now works (on EXJS 4 final), It still doesn't solve my problem. I'd Like to call a specific function when i call each treenode. Before it was really easy. Now i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in ext4 beta3 (maybe in final release too)... there is no longer `click` event....
this has changed to `itemclick` [more info](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/docs/api/Ext.tree.Panel.html#events)

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    store: store,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 300,
    width: 250,
    title: 'Files',

    listeners:{
        itemclick: function(n){
            console.info(n);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: In the middle of my rage-driven search for the answer i found the itemclick event and when i tried it, it didn't work either, but then again, "rage-driven seaches" aren't the best ones. I'll try your code and let you know. thank you for your answer.

Comment: well, no luck. it still won't fire the event. i'll post a snippet of my code above.

Comment: what is the error?? just no firing?? can i see your whole code? maybe i could help you...

Comment: itemclick is correct, and does work (I just verified it locally). Are you certain that you don't have any JS errors?  Otherwise you must have something else going on.

Comment: no errors (at least in firebug). For now i'll give this issue a rest, and focus on MVC'ing my actual code, and then, try this again, I'll accept you answer because, clearly, it is correct. Thank you

Comment: Had to un-accept the answer, because it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So, It may help some people who may be struggling with the same issue I did then.

The "itemclick" event is the way to handle leafs clicks, and it didn't work then for reasons I don't remember.

I accomplished what I needed by splitting the config I had in the database, something like

```
controllerName|functionName
```

and then call this code on the handler of the "itemclick:

```
this.getController(ctr)[fn]();
```

where ***ctr*** is the **controllerName** and ***fn*** is the **functionName**. This could easily be done with eval, but I prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get itemclick to fire with IE (fine in Chrome).   I modified my code to use 'checkchange' and it works fine.

Comment: The problem with the "checkchange" is if you want the event to trigger when clicking in the selected item. If it's not the case "checkchange" will work fine, otherwise it won't.